# Removing commas from array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this code:

```
var comment_count = instadata[0].data[i].comments.count
var comment_data = instadata[0].data[i].comments.data
var comments = [];

    $.each(comment_data, function(i, user) {
       comments.push('<li><img class="commentUserImg" src="' + user.from.profile_picture + '"><div class="commentUser">' + user.from.username + '</div><div class="commentText">' + user.text + '</div></li>');
    });
```

To display the comments.  It's an in append, directly below the $.each() inside AJAX

```
<ul class="messageComments">' + comments + '</ul>
```

When it's displayed, there are commas in between each LI element.

How can I get rid of this? Everything works fine except for the commas.

Thanks

**Updated code.  Also this is all done through AJAX**

Comment: You wouldn't happen to be using `comments.toString()` instead of `comments.join('')`, would you?

Comment: No.... This is all new to me, so you lost me at toString...

Comment: How are you using `comments`? Can you post the other code that uses that variable?

Comment: Display how? `toString` as @Blender suggested or `$.each(comment_data, function(...){ document.write();//or something similar })` ?

Comment: code updated.  I am doing all this through AJAX

Comment: :) very useful update! How do you use variable `comments` **after** you populated your data?

Comment: Here we go! Use `comments.join('')` instead as Blender suggested.

Comment: Can you explain where this might go?  Am I replacing push with join?

Comment: `<ul class="messageComments">' + comments.join('') + '</ul>`

Comment: lololol it worked.  I was having loading issues so I never saw the change.  Put this as an answer so I can give you points and gold stars n stuff

Comment: Blender was the first so this is his points :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix it with duct tape:

```
<ul class="messageComments">' + comments.join('') + '</ul>
```

Or do it right (well, just my way) the first time:

```
var comment_count = instadata[0].data[i].comments.count
var comment_data = instadata[0].data[i].comments.data
var $comments = $('<ul />', {'class': 'messageComments'});

$.each(comment_data, function(i, user) {
    var $li = $('<li />');

    $('<img />', {
        'class': 'commentUserImg',
        'src': user.from.profile_picture
    }).appendTo($li);

    $('<div />', {
        'class': 'commentUser',
        'text': user.from.username
    }).appendTo($li);

    $('<div />', {
        'class': 'commentText',
        'text': user.text
    }).appendTo($li);

    $li.appendTo($comments);
});

$comments.appendTo('body');  // Tweak this selector
```

Comment: listen bro.  duct tape or gtfo.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call join with an empty string otherwise ',' will be used by default. If you don't even call join you will be automatically using toString() and the result will be the same as join();

```
<ul class="messageComments">' + comments.join('') + '</ul>
```

Tests:

```
var a = [1,2,3,4];
console.log(a.toString()); //1,2,3,4
console.log("string: "+a); //string: 1,2,3,4
console.log(a.join());     //1,2,3,4
console.log(a.join(''));   //1234
```